# Is there a way to make the 'hamburger menu' lines in Foundation 5 thicker?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Basically, the hamburger lines (the horizontal white lines) are a bit lean :)
I wonder if there is a way to make them thicker?

My HTML:

```
 <nav class="tab-bar hide-for-medium-up">
        <section class="left-small">
            <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </section>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .menu-icon:after{
        box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 0px white, 0 0px 2px 0px white, 0 0px 2px 0px white;   
        }
```

I went into the inspector and tried to change the CSS on the fly, but nothing budged...
However these were the properties...

```
.tab-bar .menu-icon {
  text-indent: 2.1875rem;
  width: 2.8125rem;
  height: 2.8125rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML or a Demo on JSFiddle or JSBin?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? your HTML has nothing to do with the posted css!

Comment: @IS The .menu-icon class is what controls the hamburger menu...What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The little lines are controlled by the `.tab-bar .menu-icon span:after` pseudo-element.

If you want to make it thicker, you'd just increase the "height" of the pseudo element. But then you'd have to also adjust the `margin-top` property and the position of the three box shadows (which Foundation uses to generate the white horizontal lines) to compensate for the added height.

So changing these properties and leaving all the rest the same would work to make them all a bit thicker. If you've got hovers, be sure to adjust those as well. Just play around with the height, shadow positions, and margin-top until you get it how you want.

EXAMPLE:

**CSS**

```
.tab-bar .menu-icon span:after {
    height: 0.1rem;
    margin-top: -0.3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0px 1px white, 0 4px 0 1px white, 0 11px 0 1px white;
}

.tab-bar .menu-icon span:hover:after {
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 1px #b3b3b3, 0 4px 0 1px #b3b3b3, 0 11px 0 1px #b3b3b3;
}
```